# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject

Tags: javascript, asp.net, security, json

Like many ASP.NET developers, I use the Newtonsoft library to convert C# objects into JSON. Is this use of `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject` secure?

Here is how I use it in a Razor view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var json = @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model))
</script>
```

In Web Forms I might have this in my ASPX:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var json = <%= Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model)) %>
</script>
```

Comment: I'm new here, brand new actually, and may not yet get the purpose of this Stack Exchange site. Would the person who down voted the question or someone in the know give me a clue as to why it might make sense to down vote it? (Not a very friendly way to say hello...)

Comment: CodeReview is for improving working code. StackOverflow is for fixing broken code, and Programmers is for designing and 'strategizing' ways to make working code. Sometimes the cross-over is fuzzy, and this appears to be one of those times. That's all.

Answer (score 3):

Take the following result :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var json = { "key" : "</script>" }
</script>
```

Unless you HtmlEncoded your data somewhere, the "</script>" will break your code. With Html Encoding, the result should look like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var json = { "key" : "&lt;/script&gt;" }
</script>
```

To easily encode all string, you can check this solution : http://pastebin.com/R2PWZkUq

Note that this should happen only with object declare inline. JSon coming from Ajax don't have this problem.

Comment: Why would it break ? Is there something he should change to prevent that ?

Comment: @Marc-Andre check out this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4t3Mx/ Apparently the `</script>` tag takes precedence and closes the script. Definitely not what I would expect but there it is.

Comment: Here is a nice solution to fix that problem : http://pastebin.com/R2PWZkUq

Comment: That's the good old cross-site scripting attack. One never can be careful enough it seems...

Comment: So, to the question "Is this use of Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject secure?" My answer is No, and I proved why ;)

Comment: Hmmm, you found a problem with jsfiddle, because it does funky stuff. But executing this in the console or jsbin.com is perfectly safe. You have not proved much.

Comment: As @Vogel612 said, this is common cross-site scripting attack. JSBin does the same thing than JSFiddle, check this : http://jsbin.com/muhagujo/3

Comment: @konjin the question was specifically asked in respect to safety in the context of websites... Comparing that safety to the one in console is comparing apples to pears.

Answer (score 1):

An opinion question, my answer is; sure ( if you can trust Newtonsoft to escape properly all data, since JSON is such a simple format, it should not be a problem ).

Regardless,

- `var json` <- unfortunate name, the name should describe what data there is, not how it is encoded. `car`, `person`, `vendor` are properer names
- `<script type="text/javascript">` -> Nowadays, people try to avoid puttin JavaScript inside HTML, instead they just include JavaScript files. I would suggest you go down that path as well

Comment: Thanks for the response. Perhaps this is the wrong place to post this question since it is primarily about security and whether or not that particular method encodes its output in a way that is safe in a JavaScript context.

Comment: @JeremyCook Indeed ;)